# How to remove Ubuntu and Install CentOS

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

currently the PC is Ubuntu OS, I want to remove it and install with CentOS into the PC. How should I do that?

Already have the CD with the CentOS image ready. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use a specific OS to remove that particular OS for installing a different OS.  You use the procedures of the new OS to manage what you want to do with your drive.

You don't use Windows to remove Windows to install Ubuntu.  **You'd best use Ubuntu's installation disk to remove Windows** and install Ubuntu.

You don't use Ubuntu to remove Ubuntu to install Windows.  **You'd best use Windows installation disk to manage/remove Ubuntu**... and proceed with what you want to do with your drive, including deleting partitions and formatting the way you want it.

You don't use Ubuntu to remove Ubuntu to install CentOS.  **You'd best use the CentOS install disk to delete Ubuntu** and manage your disk such as delete partitions, create partitions, and so on.

If you don't have the install disk for your other OS (in this case, I see you do have your install disk for CentOS), you could boot to the Ubuntu Live Disk, run **Gparted** and delete the Ubuntu partition.

Rather than looking for your Live Ubuntu disk to work with CentOS, it might be simpler for you to use their Disk Management tools and procedure for deleting any unwanted partitions and proceeding with your intended install.

**The details would best be provided by the support channel of the OS you are moving to.**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete the Ubuntu partitions from inside the CentOS installer. Boot the installer live CD, open a partition editor such as GParted, delete Ubuntu, then proceed with the installation.

Comment: You mean I start the PC then boot at it startup? what key on the keyboard do i need to press?

Comment: @user821848 The boot menu key and BIOS key vary per motherboard. You can try F8, F10, F11, F2, and Del.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you may want to use `Acronis Disk Director` bootable CD to manage your HDDs before installing any OS (Windows, Ubuntu, CentOS, or any)..